# Is there a way to delete an object key and property?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an

```
let obj = { a:'Nasa', b:'Zezo'}
```

Is there a way to make that object look like obj = { a:'Nasa' }

I am not looking at delete operator because the key still exists.

the delete operator leaves me with {a:'Nasa', b:null }

Comment: Then you'll have to give a [mcve] with more detail about your environment, because that's not the behaviour I see in e.g. https://repl.it/languages/nodejs or read about in e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete.

Comment: `I am not looking at delete operator because the key still exists.` This is not true, so something else is causing you to not see the key disappear, as decribed in the duplicate answer. Then again, it's better to just create a new object obj2 containing only the `a` property of obj. That way the browser can still optimize obj and obj2 and you don't get issues later on when you have to check if obj still contains property `b` or not.

Comment: Yes, I don't know why the key still exists. I will accept that as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let obj = { a:'Nasa', b:'Zezo'}
console.log(obj);

delete obj.b;

console.log(obj);
```

You can use `delete obj.b` for deleting b property

Comment: yeah but the key still exists

Comment: I make a demo for delete b property, console log b property not exist